# What does "since" refer to in this text?

Tags: parsing

The sentence is:

> A bygone sweetheart is an early romantic interest remembered by someone who's since lived a long life.

Is the "since' referring to the moment of remembrance of "early romantic interest"?

Comment: The speaker has lived a long life since that *early romantic interest*. The memory exists now, and it is the *sweetheart* who is remembered.

Comment: @WeatherVane The **sweetheart** can refer to a person in general. But in this context the **bygone sweetheart** is referring to a moment which is remembered. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Airforce a "bygone sweetheart" isn't a "moment of remembrance" but a person. The 'since' refers to "an early romantic interest" or to "a sweetheart", not to "the moment of remembrance of early romantic interest" supposed by the OP – which is now.

Answer (score 1):

"Since" means "after" in this case. Another way to write this sentence would be "A bygone sweetheart is a romantic interest from early in the life of some who lived a long life after the romance ended"